How do I override built-in NodeJS version (Visual Studio 2022 + ESLint 9.10)
I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2022 (17.6.3 but now upgrading to 17.10.6) in which I am writing modules in TS/TSX and installed ESLint 9.10 to help identify issues, but it's now seeming like more trouble than it's worth.  Visual Studio 2022 shipped with Node v16.14 and it continues to launch the ESLint service using this version despite the fact that I have v21.7.3 installed on my system:

I have tried the following methods to override the version of node:
Explicitly added the path to my node install in the VS external tools and re-ordered to try and ensure all other locations are tried before falling back to VSInstalledExternalTools:

I installed Node Version Manager and 'used' my current version.
I added a .nvmrc file with "21.7.3" to the root of my project.
I added a .vscode\settings.json and added a eslint.runtime property pointing to my preferred node binary (not sure this applies to Visual Studio 2022 though)
I have a .eslintrc file but do not see how I can specify a runtime.
I also have an eslint.config.mjs, but again I suspect once this file is processed, the version of node is already pre-determined.
I have asked Bing copilot for help, but a lot of its suggestions do not seem valid (e.g. being able to specify the node runtime in Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Linting
Has anyone else run into this issue and fixed it?  I also looked for ways to upgrade VS' version of Node, but I suspect this would cause all sorts of compatibility issues elsewhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Upgrading to VS 17.10.6 did a lot.  The built-in version of NodeJS was upgraded to v18.15.0 and the "ESLint path" property that Bing mentioned is now present.

I overrode the eslint path in VS, but it still uses the built-in node executable to run the service :P
Info: ESLint server running in node v18.15.0
Info: ESLint library loaded from: C:\me\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v21.7.3\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
